# Django Model Form Field Option For Capital Letter and Auto Trim

Tags: python, django

Is there any options for form field so that any input shall be automatically converted to capital letter and trim from white spaces at the beginning and the end?

If there is not, what is the best practice in enforcing the options above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just override the `clean` method.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
         return dict([(k, v.strip().upper()) for k, v in self.cleaned_data.items()])
```

Note that this will run /after/ individual field validation.

To prevent errors with dates

```
def clean(self):
     result = {}
     for k, v in self.cleaned_data.items():
         try:
             result[k] = v.strip().upper()
         except AttributeError:
             result[k] = v
     return result
```

You could also check if the value is `isinstance(value, basestring)` and only operate on those.

Comment: `k, v` means key & value? Could you please elaborate more on the last line?

Comment: Yes, k, v = key and value. It's just returning the values of the cleaned_data without leading/trailing whitespace and in all upppercase letters.

Comment: `dict = {}; for key, value in self.cleaned_data.items(): dict[k] = v.strip().upper()`

Comment: Explicit better than implicit =)

Comment: @YujiTomita the solutions was excellent until I met a datefield :(. Is there anyway to avoid stripping the datetime (or other non-text fields)?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha, Updated with some ideas